# PyTorch Vectorized Implementation for Thresholding and Computing Jaccard Index

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, pytorch

I have been trying to optimize a code snippet which finds the optimal threshold value in a `n_patch * 256 * 256` probability map to get the highest Jaccard index against ground truth mask.

Consider a single probability map (`256 * 256`) and its ground truth (`256 * 256` with `1` and `0`). To find the optimal threshold value which yields the highest Jaccard index against the ground truth, we loop over all the probability `i` in the probability map and threshold the probability map using `i` and then compute the Jaccard index of the thresholded map against the ground truth. After looping over through all probabilities (65536 in total since 256*256) in the probability map, we will have a threshold value which generates the highest Jaccard index.

The attached code is computing `n_patch` probability maps at once instead of a single probability map. However, even I have optimized the implementation as vectorized as possible, the code still runs around **330** seconds on a GPU. Note the attached code is also executable on CPU, it will use an Nvidia GPU if you have one. A modified version of the code can be found further down.

The data are available in [here (around 24MB)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-4_gxUJRyAh8bl4fV9Ix0Qv4VMURpXNO). The file named `mask.npy` is a `n_patch * 256 * 256` binary (contains only 0 and 1) and the file named `pred_mask.npy` is a `n_patch * 256 * 256` probability (contains 0 to 1 probability) maps.

The threshold method is implemented `gen_mask` and it takes a 3D `pred_mask` and threshold on each dimension based on a threshold value vector. The `jaccard` computes the Jarrard index of a 3D thresholded mask agains the ground truth and returned a `n_patch * 1` shape array.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import time

USE_CUDA = torch.cuda.is_available()


def gen_mask(mask_pred, threshold):
    mask_pred = mask_pred.clone()
    mask_pred[:, :, :][mask_pred[:, :, :] < threshold] = 0
    mask_pred[:, :, :][mask_pred[:, :, :] >= threshold] = 1
    return mask_pred


def jaccard(prediction, ground_truth):
    union = prediction + ground_truth
    union[union == 2] = 1
    intersection = prediction * ground_truth
    union = union.sum(axis=(1, 2))
    intersection = intersection.sum(axis=(1, 2))
    ji_nonezero_union = intersection[union != 0] / union[union != 0]
    ji = ji = torch.zeros(intersection.shape)
    if USE_CUDA:
        ji = ji.cuda()
    ji[union != 0] = ji_nonezero_union
    return ji


groundtruth_masks = np.load('./masks.npy')
pred_mask = np.load('./pred_mask.npy')
n_patch = groundtruth_masks.shape[0]

groundtruth_masks = torch.from_numpy(groundtruth_masks)
groundtruth_masks = groundtruth_masks.type(torch.float)
pred_mask = torch.from_numpy(pred_mask)

vector_pred = pred_mask.view(n_patch, -1)

best_threshold_val = torch.zeros(n_patch)
best_jaccard_idx = torch.zeros(n_patch)

if USE_CUDA:
    groundtruth_masks = groundtruth_masks.cuda()
    pred_mask = pred_mask.cuda()
    vector_pred = vector_pred.cuda()
    best_threshold_val = best_threshold_val.cuda()
    best_jaccard_idx = best_jaccard_idx.cuda()

start = time.time()
# I think this outer for loop is inevitable since
# vector_pred.shape[1] is 65536
# so we cannot simply create a matrix with n_patch * 65536 * 256 * 256
# which is too large even for a GPU to handle
for i in range(vector_pred.shape[1]):
    cur_threshold_val = vector_pred[:, i]
    cur_threshold_val = cur_threshold_val.reshape(n_patch, 1, 1)
    thresholded_mask = gen_mask(pred_mask.squeeze(), cur_threshold_val)
    thresholded_mask = thresholded_mask.type(torch.float)
    ji = jaccard(thresholded_mask, groundtruth_masks)
    cur_threshold_val = cur_threshold_val.squeeze()
    best_threshold_val[ji >
                    best_jaccard_idx] = cur_threshold_val[ji > best_jaccard_idx]
    best_jaccard_idx[ji > best_jaccard_idx] = ji[ji > best_jaccard_idx]
    print(i, '/', vector_pred.shape[1], end="\r")
end = time.time()
print(best_threshold_val)
print(best_jaccard_idx)
print(end - start)
```

Also, the output:

```
Best Threshold: tensor([6.8828e-01, 4.7082e-01, 1.2254e-01, 3.4189e-01, 2.8555e-01, 2.4655e-01,
        4.9444e-01, 5.9245e-01, 5.0390e-01, 1.7931e-01, 2.3205e-01, 3.8314e-01,
        4.5103e-01, 3.6109e-01, 3.4614e-01, 3.8766e-01, 3.6444e-01, 2.3667e-01,
        2.0029e-01, 8.0435e-01, 4.9489e-01, 2.8066e-01, 1.4230e-04, 1.8089e-01,
        2.2194e-01, 3.7781e-01, 3.5074e-01, 5.4690e-03, 2.6937e-01, 1.7834e-01,
        2.2150e-01, 1.8330e-01], device='cuda:0')

Best Jaccard Index: tensor([0.9978, 0.9936, 0.9975, 0.9956, 0.9921, 0.9977, 0.9938, 0.9972, 0.9987,
        0.9983, 0.9974, 0.9972, 0.9955, 0.9851, 0.9979, 0.9938, 0.9960, 0.9936,
        0.9967, 0.9852, 0.9963, 0.9924, 0.9890, 0.9946, 0.9954, 0.9971, 0.9945,
        0.9919, 0.9964, 0.9947, 0.9920, 0.9977], device='cuda:0')
```

Any suggestions to optimize the code snippet are welcome!

---

Update:

I managed to speed up the script by 100s using PyTorch logical `and` and `or`. However, this operation is only supported for type `torch.uint8` which means I have to do type conversion. Now the performance is **232** seconds on a GPU.

The following is the modified version:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import time

USE_CUDA = torch.cuda.is_available()


def gen_mask(mask_pred, threshold):
    mask_pred = mask_pred.clone()
    mask_pred[:, :, :][mask_pred[:, :, :] < threshold] = 0
    mask_pred[:, :, :][mask_pred[:, :, :] >= threshold] = 1
    return mask_pred.type(torch.uint8)


def jaccard(prediction, ground_truth):
    union = prediction | ground_truth
    intersection = prediction & ground_truth
    union = union.sum(axis=(1, 2))
    intersection = intersection.sum(axis=(1, 2))
    union = union.type(torch.float)
    intersection = intersection.type(torch.float)
    union_nonzero_idx = union != 0
    cur_jaccard_idx = torch.zeros(intersection.shape)
    if USE_CUDA:
        cur_jaccard_idx = cur_jaccard_idx.cuda()
    cur_jaccard_idx[union_nonzero_idx] = intersection[union_nonzero_idx] / union[union_nonzero_idx]
    return cur_jaccard_idx


groundtruth_masks = np.load('./masks.npy')
pred_mask = np.load('./pred_mask.npy')
n_patch = groundtruth_masks.shape[0]

groundtruth_masks = torch.from_numpy(groundtruth_masks)
groundtruth_masks = groundtruth_masks.type(torch.uint8)
pred_mask = torch.from_numpy(pred_mask)

vector_pred = pred_mask.view(n_patch, -1)

best_threshold_val = torch.zeros(n_patch)
best_jaccard_idx = torch.zeros(n_patch)

if USE_CUDA:
    groundtruth_masks = groundtruth_masks.cuda()
    pred_mask = pred_mask.cuda()
    vector_pred = vector_pred.cuda()
    best_threshold_val = best_threshold_val.cuda()
    best_jaccard_idx = best_jaccard_idx.cuda()

start = time.time()
# I think this outer for loop is inevitable since
# vector_pred.shape[1] is 65536
# so we cannot simply create a matrix with n_patch * 65536 * 256 * 256
# which is too large even for a GPU to handle
for i in range(vector_pred.shape[1]):
    cur_threshold_val = vector_pred[:, i]
    cur_threshold_val = cur_threshold_val.reshape(n_patch, 1, 1)
    thresholded_mask = gen_mask(pred_mask.squeeze(), cur_threshold_val)
    cur_jaccard_idx = jaccard(thresholded_mask, groundtruth_masks)
    cur_threshold_val = cur_threshold_val.squeeze()
    best_threshold_val[cur_jaccard_idx >
                    best_jaccard_idx] = cur_threshold_val[cur_jaccard_idx > best_jaccard_idx]
    best_jaccard_idx[cur_jaccard_idx > best_jaccard_idx] = cur_jaccard_idx[cur_jaccard_idx > best_jaccard_idx]
    print(i, '/', vector_pred.shape[1], end="\r")
end = time.time()
print(best_threshold_val)
print(best_jaccard_idx)
print(end - start)
```

Comment: @dfhwze Sorry my bad. I have updated the description with more details. Please let me know if you need me to elaborate more :)

Comment: Not sure whether this helps: the `scipy` library has a built-in function for computing the [jaccard distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard.html).

Comment: @GZ0 Thanks for your suggestion. It seems this method only takes two 1D arrays, which unfortunately does not apply for this problem since we essentially have shape `n_patch * 256 * 256` or `n_patch * 65536` (flat the last two-dimension). But thanks for your comment!

Comment: I rolled this back to revision 10. Editing a question based on feedback from answers is outside of policy. If you want to post the new code, please do so in a separate question.

Comment: @Reinderien The edits actually happened before I posted my answer and I wrote my answer based on the edited post.

Comment: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9341/what-do-we-do-with-out-of-sync-questions

Comment: I've rolled back the rollback. If anyone has any questions whatsoever about what is happening, see [this meta question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9341/52915) or find me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a different approach is needed to achieve a better performance. The current approach recomputes the Jaccard similarity from scratch for each possible threshold value. However, going from one threshold to the next, only a small fraction of prediction values change as well as the intersection and the union. Therefore a lot of unnecessary computation is performed.

A better approach can first compute for each patch a histogram of the prediction probabilities given ground truth = 1, using the thresholds as bin edges. The frequency counts in each bin give the amount of predictions affected going from one threshold to the next. Therefore, the Jaccard similarity values for all thresholds can be computed directly from cummulative frequency counts derived from the histogram.

In your case, the prediction probabilities are used directly as thresholds. Therefore the histograms coincide with the inputs sorted by the probabilities. Consider the following example input probablities and true labels:

```
Label    1    1    0    0    1     0    0    0
Prob     0.9  0.8  0.7  0.6  0.45  0.4  0.2  0.1
```

The labels themselves are also the counts of true positive instances within each interval. Given a threshold \$t\$ and its index \$i\$, \$|Label \cap Predicted|\$ is just the sum of labels with indices \$\leq i\$, which is the cumulative sum of labels until \$i\$. Also note that \$|Predicted|=i+1\$ and \$Label\$ is the count of true positive instances. Therefore the Jaccard similarity

$$
\begin{align*}
Jaccard(Label, Predicted) & = \frac{|Label \cap Predicted|}{|Label \cup Predicted|} \\
 & = \frac{|Label \cap Predicted|}{|Label|+|Predicted|-|Label \cap Predicted|} \\
 & = \frac{cumsum(Label, i)}{(\text{# of true positive instances}) + i + 1 - cumsum(Label, i)}
\end{align*}
$$

This computation can be easily vectorized for all possible \$i\$s to get a Jaccard similarity vector for every threshold.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think it is a good suggestion. I will need some time to implement this idea and will update the speedup as soon as possible :)

Comment: @yiping You're welcome. Just remember that in case you ever want to post **new code** for further improvements it needs to be done in a new post as required by the policy (you see what happened from the comments if this is not obeyed). The new post can link to this post as a reference.

Comment: So I implement your algorithms and it now runs 0.02s on a GPU and 0.25s on a CPU. This is very impressive! Thanks, mate. Can I update the code in this question for future reference? (I do not need further improvement :)

Comment: You can reply to your own question and post the code as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the answer of @GZ0, the performance of this code snippet is now around **0.0344s** on a GPU and around **0.2511s** on a CPU. The implementation of @GZ0's algorithm is attached. Please do not hesitate to suggest any modifications to make the code snippet more pythonic :)

```
import timeit
import torch
import argparse
import numpy as np

USE_CUDA = torch.cuda.is_available()


def find_optimal_threshold(pred_mask, groundtruth_masks):
    n_patch = groundtruth_masks.shape[0]

    groundtruth_masks_tensor = torch.from_numpy(groundtruth_masks)
    pred_mask_tensor = torch.from_numpy(pred_mask)

    if USE_CUDA:
        groundtruth_masks_tensor = groundtruth_masks_tensor.cuda()
        pred_mask_tensor = pred_mask_tensor.cuda()

    vector_pred = pred_mask_tensor.view(n_patch, -1)
    vector_gt = groundtruth_masks_tensor.view(n_patch, -1)
    vector_pred, sort_pred_idx = torch.sort(vector_pred, descending=True)
    vector_gt = vector_gt[torch.arange(vector_gt.shape[0])[
        :, None], sort_pred_idx]
    gt_cumsum = torch.cumsum(vector_gt, dim=1)
    gt_total = gt_cumsum[:, -1].reshape(n_patch, 1)
    predicted = torch.arange(start=1, end=vector_pred.shape[1] + 1)
    if USE_CUDA:
        predicted = predicted.cuda()
    gt_cumsum = gt_cumsum.type(torch.float)
    gt_total = gt_total.type(torch.float)
    predicted = predicted.type(torch.float)
    jaccard_idx = gt_cumsum / (gt_total + predicted - gt_cumsum)
    max_jaccard_idx, max_indices = torch.max(jaccard_idx, dim=1)
    max_indices = max_indices.reshape(-1, 1)
    best_threshold = vector_pred[torch.arange(vector_pred.shape[0])[
        :, None], max_indices]
    best_threshold = best_threshold.reshape(-1)

    return best_threshold


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--pred_mask_path', type=str,
                        required=False, default='./pred_mask.npy')
    parser.add_argument('--groundtruth_mask_path', type=str, required=False,
                        default='./masks.npy')
    parser.add_argument('--run_times', type=int, required=False,
                        default=10000)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    groundtruth_masks = np.load(args.groundtruth_mask_path)
    pred_mask = np.load(args.pred_mask_path)
    t = timeit.timeit(lambda: find_optimal_threshold(pred_mask, groundtruth_masks), number=args.run_times)
    print(t / args.run_times, 'seconds')
```

Comment: Good job. I hope you have verified the correctness of the implementation (e.g., by comparing the results with your earlier implementation). Meanwhile, `gt_total` can actually be retrieved from the last row of `gt_cumsum` rather than computed again.

Comment: Timing program execution is normally done using the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) module or `%timeit` / `%%timeit` in IPython.

Comment: Yes, I have verified the correctness. It agrees with the naive implementation. Oh yeah, you are right! I will update it right now.

Comment: Putting the entire code block in a string looks ugly. Instead, the code to be measured can be wrapped into a function `test_func` with no arguments and then called by `timeit.timeit(test_func, ...)` (you could find a better function name BTW).

Comment: @GZ0 Thanks for the suggestions :) I have changed them. Cheers

Comment: There's a typo in the name `find_optiaml_threshold`. Also, accessing / updating global variables generally has some performance overhead (although it is probably negligible in this case). A cleaner way is to pass `groundtruth_masks` and `pred_mask` as function arguments so that the function itself can be directly reused by others. And then in the measurement code, which does not need to be global, you make another wrapper function without arguments. The wrapper function can also be a `lambda` such as `timeit.timeit(lambda:find_optimal_threshold(...), ...)`.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! While OPs are [encouraged to answer their own questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) bear in mind that ["_Your answer must meet the standards of a Code Review answer, just like any other answer. **Describe what you changed, and why.** Code-only answers that don't actually review the code are insufficient and are subject to deletion_"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)... perhaps adding a new question would be a better solution

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I will re-edit my answer based on your link as soon as possible :) Thank you!